# Do Twig for loops run in a predicatable order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, twig

I have a `for` loop in a Twig template.

```
{% for v in details.variants %}
```

Here `details.variants` is an array which has come from a database:

```
[variants] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 8711
                [Title] => Variant the First
                [Code] => 
                [Price] => 6989.99
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 8713
                [Title] => Variant the Second
                [Code] => 
                [Price] => 769.99
            )

    )
```

For some reason, in the rendered HTML, Variant the Second appears first, and then Variant the First. The data is definitely coming out of the database in the correct order, and the array being passed to Twig is correct.

This is inconsistent from one page to another. Some are in the correct order; some are not. However, each individual page is consistent: multiple refreshes show the same order. (All these pages are using the same Twig template.) I'm also unable to reproduce it on my own machine, which seems to always show the correct provided order.

Does Twig respect the supplied array order? Does it make a difference whether the array has string or integer keys?

Comment: How did you make sure that `the data is definitely coming out of the database in the correct order, and the array being passed to Twig is correct`? Since you say you can't produce this on your own machine it raises some question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `twig` does respect the order as it's just a `foreach` underneath

<kbd>twig</kbd>

```
{% set variants = [
    {'foo':'bar', },
    {'foo':'foo', },
] %}

{% for variant in variants %}
    {{ variant.foo }}
{% endfor %}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 1
        $context["variants"] = array(0 => array("foo" => "bar"), 1 => array("foo" => "foo"));
        // line 5
        echo "
";
        // line 6
        $context['_parent'] = $context;
        $context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable((isset($context["variants"]) || array_key_exists("variants", $context) ? $context["variants"] : (function () { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('Variable "variants" does not exist.', 6, $this->getSourceContext()); })()));
        foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["_key"] => $context["variant"]) {
            // line 7
            echo "    ";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, twig_get_attribute($this->env, $this->getSourceContext(), $context["variant"], "foo", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "
";
        }
        $_parent = $context['_parent'];
        unset($context['_seq'], $context['_iterated'], $context['_key'], $context['variant'], $context['_parent'], $context['loop']);
        $context = array_intersect_key($context, $_parent) + $_parent;
    }
```